# Why does my app works when build by Linux eclipse but doesn't on Windows Eclipse?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, windows, shell

I can't understand why the *exactly* same code is running just fine when it's builded by Eclipse on Linux but **doesn't run correctly** when the application is build by Windows Eclipse. Both use the same eclipse version.

They both execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` , but it only works when build by the Linux version.

Here's my Activity

```
package com.example.volt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String commandToExecute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        commandToExecute = "/system/xbin/su";
        executeShellCommand(commandToExecute);

        Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);


        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                commandToExecute = "/system/xbin/su -c /system/bin/service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui";
                executeShellCommand(commandToExecute);

            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                commandToExecute = "/system/xbin/su -c /system/bin/am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService";
                executeShellCommand(commandToExecute);

            }
        });



    }

    private boolean executeShellCommand(String command) {
        try {

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the binary on Windows when it fails? Or did you just build it on Windows and then try to run it on a linux machine?

Comment: This is a project I builded on Linux, using eclipse. The shell command works, it removes the status bar by killing a Activity from the SystemUI on the Android device. When I import the exactly same project on Windows, also using eclipse, it executes the Runtime command but doesn't work.

Comment: there is no `su` binary on windows, which is why your `commandToExecute` fails...

Comment: Oh, this is only running on the android device? Not on either host machine. That makes sense. And leaves me with no ideas.